# RestAPI with multidimensional data/multilevel data in sql database in node.js?

Tags: sql, node.js, rest

In node.js it is recommended that we should not use blocking calls to database or any other place. But if I go according to this rule I am facing a problem with rest api with sql database. It might be achievable in nosql databases.

**Problem :**

I have a table in database with columns **username,col1,column2,time**.
The rest api data I want is something like this

```
{ 
  username:A,
  max(col1):123,
  deviation_column2: [{
       time:10:00,
       column2:54
     },
     { 
       time:10:05,
       column2:59
     }
  ]
},
{ 
  username:B,
  max(col1):123,
  deviation_column2: [{
       time:10:00,
       column2:54
     },
     { 
       time:10:05,
       column2:59
     }
  ]
}
```

I want to generate rest api which gives me avg of col1, and standard deviation of column2 with time.

I could achieve this by two blocking calls to database and merging the data but in Node.js it is not advisable, so **how can I give this type of rest response to my client without using blocking calls?**

I can achieve the following result separately by using stdev and max function on group of username and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve such results easily with [Fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) and their derivatives. [`wait.for`](https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor) is especially pretty. With these tools, you can run synchronous calls to database without blocking the event loop.

Notice that Fibers are a bit controversial, as they significantly change the way you think in Node, albeit there's no actual disadvantage in using them.